# XSLT if two values of an element match then merge cells?

Tags: xml, xslt, xhtml

I'm trying to create a piece of XHTML out of an XML and a XSLT file.

I want to test if the value of two or more XML elements coincide with other ones in the table, in which case, I want those cells to be merged in the result XHTML file.

I'll use a simple w3schools example for simplicity. (More people should do this on stackoverflow).

Here is the XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<catalog>
<cd>
    <title>Empire Burlesque</title>
    <artist>Bob Dylan</artist>
</cd>
<cd>
    <title>Empire Burlesque</title>
    <artist>Bonnie Tyler</artist>
</cd>
<cd>
    <title>Empire Burlesque</title>
    <artist>Mr G</artist>
</cd>
<cd>
    <title>Greatest Hits</title>
    <artist>Dolly Parton</artist>
</cd>
</catalog>
```

Here is the XSLT:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:template match="/">
<html>
<body>
<h2>My CD Collection</h2>
<table border="1">
<tr bgcolor="#9acd32">
  <th>Title</th>
  <th>Artist</th>
</tr>
<xsl:for-each select="catalog/cd">
<tr>
  <xsl:choose>
  <xsl:when test="count(title) %gr 2">
     <td rowspan="2"><xsl:value-of select="title"/></td>
  </xsl:when>
  <xsl:otherwise>
     <td><xsl:value-of select="title"/></td>
  </xsl:otherwise>
  </xsl:choose>
  <td><xsl:value-of select="artist"/></td>
  </tr>
  </xsl:for-each>
  </table>
  </body>
  </html>
  </xsl:template>
  </xsl:stylesheet>
```

The two elements in the XSLT that are wrong are: the TEST and ROWSPAN.

1. How do I test if there are more than one instance for a title? (In this case Empire Burlesque)
2. How do I tell the program to merge these two cells in that case (so the output is one cell that says Empire Burlesque) with rowspan 3.

NOTE: Please don't tell me to do test='Empire Burlesque'. I want it to work for other repeating instances if I where to add them in. Thank you.

Comment: The solution to grouping problems like this depends very strongly on whether you are using XSLT 1.0 or 2.0 (it's a lot easier in 2.0!). So you need to tell us which version you are targeting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I won't tell you to do test='Empire Burlesque' but I will tell you to read up on a technique in XSLT 1.0 called [Muenchian Grouping](http://www.jenitennison.com/xslt/grouping/muenchian.html), which will allow you to group your `cd` elements by distinct `title`

In your case, you start off by defining a key to look up the cds by title

```
<xsl:key name="cds" match="cd" use="title" />
```

Then, to get the distinct titles (or rather, to get the `cd` elements with the first occurrence of each distinct title), you would use this expression

```
<xsl:for-each select="catalog/cd[generate-id() = generate-id(key('cds', title)[1])]">
```

Within this loop you would group you would then get all the cds with a matching title by using the key. For example, to see if you needed a rowspan, you would do this

```
<xsl:if test="count(key('cds', title)) > 1">
```

Try this XSLT

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="html" doctype-public="XSLT-compat" omit-xml-declaration="yes" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" />

<xsl:key name="cds" match="cd" use="title" />

<xsl:template match="/">
<html>
<body>
<h2>My CD Collection</h2>
<table border="1">
<tr bgcolor="#9acd32">
  <th>Title</th>
  <th>Artist</th>
</tr>
<xsl:for-each select="catalog/cd[generate-id() = generate-id(key('cds', title)[1])]">
<tr>
  <td>
      <xsl:if test="key('cds', title)[2]">
          <xsl:attribute name="rowspan">
              <xsl:value-of select="count(key('cds', title))" />
          </xsl:attribute>
      </xsl:if>
      <xsl:value-of select="title"/>
  </td>
  <td><xsl:value-of select="artist"/></td>
</tr>
<xsl:for-each select="key('cds', title)[position() > 1]">
<tr>
    <td>
      <xsl:value-of select="artist"/>
    </td>
</tr>    
</xsl:for-each>
  </xsl:for-each>
  </table>
  </body>
  </html>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: It works, thank you for the quick reply. However, it I were to add another cd also called empire burlesque it stops working. Is there any simple way of making it so it works for more than just two repeating elements?

Comment: It may be a little bit trickier, but can you edit your question to show an example with three "Empire burlesque" cds, and the output you expect? Thank you!

Comment: Done, I added another CD called empire burlesque. Now I want a similar result: this time, Empire Burlesque should have rowspan 3 and encompass the artists Bob Dylan, Bonnie Tyler and Mr G

Comment: Actually, it was not tricky at all. There was just a mistake in my XSLT as I was not outputing `tr` elements where I should have been. I have corrected my answer.

Comment: Awesome. Thank you so much, really!